# Getting proper math typesetting with Cambria?

Tags: luatex, delimiters, math-fonts

When I switched from Calibri to Cambria in LuaLaTeX, a `\middle/` lost its correct size. I then tinkered with combinations of `fontspec`, `unicode-math` and `mathastext`, but none seems to work. I didn't play around with Calibri, as I don't want to use that anymore:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

%% ---------------------------------------------------------
%% Variant A: OK, except not Cambria

%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage{amsmath}

%% ---------------------------------------------------------
%% Variant B: not OK, dash to small

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Cambria}[BoldFont = CambriaB]
\setsansfont{Corbel}[Numbers = Lining]
\setmonofont{Consolas}[Scale = 0.93]
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Cambria Math} % needs unicode-math?
\usepackage{amsmath}

%% ---------------------------------------------------------
%% Variant C: not OK, wrong math font

%\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Cambria}[BoldFont = CambriaB]
%\setsansfont{Corbel}[Numbers = Lining]
%\setmonofont{Consolas}[Scale = 0.93]
%\usepackage{amsmath}

%% ---------------------------------------------------------
%% Variant D: dash and parentheses OK, but wrong math font for sum and fraction line

%\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Cambria}[BoldFont = CambriaB]
%\setsansfont{Corbel}[Numbers = Lining]
%\setmonofont{Consolas}[Scale = 0.93]
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage[italic]{mathastext}

\begin{document}
Some math stuff:
\begin{gather}
    E = m c^2\\
    \sum_{i = 1}^{n} i = \frac12 n (n + 1)\\
    \left.\left(86400\,\text{s}\right)\middle/\!\left(86400\,\frac{\text{s}}{\text{d}}\right)\right. = 1\,\text{d}
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Did you receive error messages? If yes please show them...

Comment: @Mensch no, it just doesn't stretch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fraction slash U+2044 is set up as extendable in Cambria Math, but `unicode-math` doesn't define it as a delimiter, you can access it directly:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

%% ---------------------------------------------------------
%% Variant A: OK, except not Cambria

%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage{amsmath}

%% ---------------------------------------------------------
%% Variant B: not OK, dash to small

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Cambria}%[BoldFont = CambriaB]
\setsansfont{Corbel}[Numbers = Lining]
\setmonofont{Consolas}[Scale = 0.93]
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Cambria Math} % needs unicode-math?
\usepackage{amsmath}

%% ---------------------------------------------------------
%% Variant C: not OK, wrong math font

%\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Cambria}[BoldFont = CambriaB]
%\setsansfont{Corbel}[Numbers = Lining]
%\setmonofont{Consolas}[Scale = 0.93]
%\usepackage{amsmath}

%% ---------------------------------------------------------
%% Variant D: dash and parentheses OK, but wrong math font for sum and fraction line

%\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Cambria}[BoldFont = CambriaB]
%\setsansfont{Corbel}[Numbers = Lining]
%\setmonofont{Consolas}[Scale = 0.93]
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage[italic]{mathastext}

\begin{document}


Some math stuff:
\begin{gather}
    E = m c^2\\
    \sum_{i = 1}^{n} i = \frac12 n (n + 1)\\
    \left.\left(86400\,\text{s}\right)\middle/\!\left(86400\,\frac{\text{s}}{\text{d}}\right)\right. = 1\,\text{d}\\
    \left.\left(86400\,\text{s}\right)\middle\fracslash\!\left(86400\,\frac{\text{s}}{\text{d}}\right)\right. = 1\,\text{d}\\
    \left.\left(86400\,\text{s}\right)\middle\divslash\!\left(86400\,\frac{\text{s}}{\text{d}}\right)\right. = 1\,\text{d}\\
    \left.\left(86400\,\text{s}\right)\middle\Udelimiter 0 0 "2044\!\left(86400\,\frac{\text{s}}{\text{d}}\right)\right. = 1\,\text{d}
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is that a common thing with system wide fonts, or rather Cambria specific?

Comment: @ehak Cambria specific, Opentype Math is still somewhat experimental and fonts vary in supported features more than you might hope,